How to send only new log at CloudWatch Agent?
First of all, please understand that English may be strange using a translator.
I use AWS CloudWatch log agent to push my application log to AWS Cloudwatch.
I'm looking for the option of sending only new logs to CloudWatch.
Now, when a new log is logged, the entire file is send, resulting in many duplicate logs.
I only want to send the newly added log line to prevent this.
Maybe in the old CloudWatch settings, I could specify the starting location with initial_position = end_of_file, but does Unified CloudWatch also have this option?
I couldn't find it in the official document.
I'm leaving the current file settings. I'd appreciate it if you could let me know what to add.
"logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
        "files": {
            "collect_list": [
                {
                    "file_path": "<path>/test.log",
                        "log_group_name": "test.log",
                        "log_stream_name": "test.{date}",
                        "timestamp_format": "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I have log like
log1
log2

If new log log3 added, I want a result like
log1
log2
log3

But now, I have result like
log1
log1
log2
log2
log3 

